# How to set Electron size in Nightmare.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nightmare

The [Nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) docs don't specify how to set the [browser](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#new-browserwindowoptions) details.

I'm guessing it's like this, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
const nightmare = new Nightmare({'show': show, 'BrowserWindow': {height: 900}});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation isn't *terrifically* clear, but the intent is to show that the Nightmare options are passed to  `BrowserWindow`, effectively using the same options set.

In other words,

```
const nightmare = new Nightmare({ show: show, height: 900});
```

... should work.